# Build DLL in MinGW/MSYS2 without declspec(dllexport)

Tags: dll, mingw, msys2

Is there any way to compile a Windows DLL in MinGW/MSYS2 with the desired exported symbols without annotating the source code with `_declspec(dllexport)`?

Answer (score 2):

You probably already solved the problem, it has been over a year, but other people might have this problem, so:

Yes in MinGW you don't have to add the `declspec(dllexport)` and a good reason might be that you just want to use someone else's library source without modifying/forking it.

Here is an example **`lib.c`** that will be compiled into a DLL and exporting `func` with the Makefile below:

```
int func(int A) {
    return A*2;
}
```

And a **`lib.h`** for usage in the executable:

```
typedef int func_type(int A);
```

The **`Makefile`**, but make sure that you fix the indentation: the two indented lines need a tab instead of 4 spaces:

```
all: lib.dll ex.exe

lib.dll: lib.c
    gcc -o lib.dll -shared lib.c -Wall

ex.exe: ex.c
    gcc -o ex.exe ex.c -Wall
```

Note that the `-shared` is, what makes the output into a valid DLL and makes it export `func`.

Example **`ex.c`** for testing purposes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "lib.h"
int main(void) {
    void* Lib = LoadLibraryW(L"lib.dll");
    assert(Lib);
    func_type (*func) = (func_type*)GetProcAddress(Lib, "func");
    assert(func);
    printf("%i\n", func(11)); // should output 22
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I honestly don't remember what I did so i can't mark it but you get an upvote.